# remember me cookies gets deleted symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I am trying to configure remember me feature of symfony using their default mechanism as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html); but couldn't make it work.

Cookie named REMEMBERME is created, but is set to deleted and its expire date is 1970. This is why I suppose remember me function is not working. However, when I use (always_remember_me: true) in security.yml, the code works nicely but it doesn't suite my purpose. Using (always_remember_me: true) even if user doesn't check REMEMBER ME checkbox in UI the cookie gets created.

Any help is highly appreciated

I am using the version 2.3.7

This is my complete security.yml file:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # a year
                domain:   ~ 
                path: /
                remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
                #always_remember_me: true
            form_login:
                login_path:  _my_login
                check_path:  _my_login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /out/homepage
                remember_me:    true
            logout:
                path:   _my_logout
                target: _my_login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED  }

    providers:
        chain_provider:
          chain:
            providers: [in_memory, user_db]

        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: user, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                    admin: { password: admin, roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'] }
        user_db:
          entity: {class: ProjectName\StoreBundle\Entity\User, property: username}

    encoders:
        ProjectName\StoreBundle\Entity\User: 
                algorithm: sha1
                iterations: 1
                encode_as_base64: false
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="_my_login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

         return  array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'         => $error,
            );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="_my_login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
    }
```

Comment: I face the same problem. The REMEMBERME cookie is set at time of login. Now when the session expires and I reload the site, the server sends response header to delete that cookie. But I don't know WHY? It should only delete it on logout but it does during session expiration also.Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the value attribute inside the input tag. After removing it, it worked for now. :)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked /> Remember me
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the checkbox is named incorrectly. It should have the 'name' attribute set to '_remember_me' to make the magic happen. Can you post the content of the form template?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Please read my comment above. I feel there is some problem in symfony backend.